# Difference between setting the number of epochs or iterating `model.fit`

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

Is there a qualitative difference between setting the number of epochs to N or iterating `model.fit` N times?
Can the classifier suffer from under-performance?
More precisely, are the following:

```
for i in range(N):
    if i == 0:
       model.fit(...,epochs=1)
       model.save_weights(..)
    else:
       model.load_weights(..)
       model.fit(...,epochs=1)
       model.save_weights(..)
```

```
model.fit(...,epochs = N)
```

equivalent in terms of classifying performance? What about computational performance?

Comment: You could try testing it yourself and then ask *why* they are different if they are?

Comment: `save_weights()` does not save the optimizer's state and its parameters. Hence, could make a difference.